# Difference aggregation, acquaintance and composition (as used by Gang Of Four)

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have been reading *Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software* by Erich Gamma et al. and got to the part explaining *aggregation* and *acquaintance* (page 22-23). Here is an excerpt (sorry if it is too long but I deemed all of it to be important to explain this question):

> Consider the distinction between object **aggregation** and **acquaintance** and how differently they manifest themselves at compile- and run-times. Aggregation implies that one object owns or is responsible for another object. Generally we speak of an object *having* or being *part of* another object. Aggregation implies that an aggregate object and its owner have identical lifetimes.
>
> Acquaintance implies that an object merely *knows of* another object. Sometimes acquaintance is called ”association” or the “using” relationship. Acquainted objects may request operations of each other, but they aren’t responsible for each other. Acquaintance is a weaker relationship than aggregation and suggests much looser coupling between objects.
>
> […]
>
> Ultimately, acquaintance and aggregation are determined more by intent than by explicit language mechanisms. The distinction may be hard to see in the compile-time structure, but it's significant. Aggregation relationships tend to be fewer and more permanent than acquaintance. Acquaintances, in contrast, are made and remade more frequently, sometimes existing only for the duration of an operation. Acquaintances are more dynamic as well, making them more difficult to discern in the source code.

The confusing part for me is that *aggregation* described here has traits of *composition*: a composing object *manages* other objects and their lifetimes are bound.

On the other hand *acquaintance* defined in that excerpt has traits of *aggregation*: an aggregating object *knows about* other objects but it does not manage them.

Also the part

> Sometimes acquaintance is called “association” or the “using” relationship.

is confusing as I thought that both *aggregation* and *composition* are forms of *association* with *aggregation* being the less coupling one.

Can it be that the authors are referring to *aggregation* as *acquaintance* and to *composition* as *aggregation*, or am I missing something?

Comment: Concepts overlap. Those are similar but they are also distinct.

Comment: The authors use OMT *aggregation* to refer to UML *composite aggregation* (AKA *composition*), cf. [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65209748/2326961).

Answer (score 11):

What I have been taught is as you write:

> Can it be that the authors are referring to **aggregation** as
> **acquaintance** and to **composition** as **aggregation** or am I missing
> something?

Yes. My understanding is:

1. At the beginning, when you are doing the (rough) *analysis*, think in terms of **[association](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html)**. In this phase it is usually enough.
2. Later, when you describe the (detailed) *design*, you need to decide the ownership of the objects, their lifecycle, instantiation, cleanup etc.

   Specify the associations in deeper detail - divide them into two groups:

   - **[aggregation](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/aggregation.html)** (the more free relationship where the objects may live independently) and
   - **[composition](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/composition.html)** (the more tight relationship where one object is responsible for the life cycle of the other).

However, not depending which of the terminology you are using (the one of the Gang of Four or the UML definition as I described here), all the terms mean **relationship between *whole* objects**, and **not** only that a single method of an object **uses** a local variable (or a parameter, which is just a special type of a local variable) with another object.

```java
class Car {
    // There is an association between Car and RegistrationPlate.
    // This association is either composition or aggregation.
    // The type of association is *not* deferrable from the syntax here.
    // This is purely the design decision and depends on many things,
    // both technical and business logic.
    // In some countries the registration plates are movable among cars,
    // in others they are cancelled when you scrap the car.
    RegistrationPlate registrationPlate;

    // Technically, there is an association between Car and List
    // but we rarely call it like that. Instead we say
    // "there is one to many association between Car and Tyre"
    // and the List is viewed just as an implementation detail.
    List<Tyre> tyres;

    // There is neither association nor composition nor aggregation 
    // between Car and Engine and Fuel
    // but instead  Car <<uses>> Engine   and   Car <<uses>> Fuel.
    void doSomething(Fuel fuel) {
        Engine engine = new Engine();
        // (method parameter fuel is just a special case of a local method variable)
        ...
    }
}
```

[image]

In the code, both the aggregation and the composition might look the same at the first glance, especially in the languages with garbage collector (like Java, Kotlin or C#), where the programmers do not have to care *so much* about the clean-up **[Note 1]**. However, the difference is in the responsibility for the life-cycle of the associated object:

- In case of the *composition*, it is mandatory that the "container" object is responsible for all the necessary cleanup of its component.
- In case of the *aggregation*, the situation is much more complicated, because the aggregated object has (can have) its own life and you must be very careful to properly implement the cleanup.

---

[Note 1] Even in languages with garbage collector, you *also* often have to think about clean-up, such as closing opened connections, releasing file handles, and taking care of effectively losing reference to objects so they are GC eligible - not forgetting unused objects in collections, using [weak references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference), or other techniques. This is out of scope of this question.

Comment: +1:  This is the UML definition, and the more commonly used now.  UML and the GoF book came at about the same time and used a few words differently.

Answer (score 2):

Composition: When a class composes of a data member of another class.

```
Class A
{
   B ObjB;
}
```

Aggregation: When method of a class creates object of some other class within its scope

```
void A::methA()
{
   B* ObjB= new B();
   delete ObjB;
}
```

Acquintance/Using: When method of a class accepts reference to object of another class as argument

```
void A:methA (B& objB) 
{

}
```

Comment: You example is bound to C++ philosophy - Not all the OOP languages distinguish between objects and pointers to objects. The difference between your examples (composition and aggregation) is just **syntactical**. The difference between these two notions is, on the other hand, **essential** and not bound to one specific language. It's about **responsibility** for the attached object's life cycle, not about the specific way of deleting the object, such as the automatic releasing (as in your first example) and explicit releasing (as in your second example).

Comment: @HonzaZidek He explained it through example. Better than your answer :) Reading your answer I was stuck at "analysis view" and "design view". Huge amount of theory is best explained through examples. +1

Comment: @MartinBerger I understand your point, but however it adds something to catch the meaning of the terms, it is also misleading. The reasons are two: 1. The aggregation example is wrong, this is *not* what aggregation is. This is also only another example of using. Aggregation is a relationship between two classes/objects, not between a method and another object. 2. Even in C++, you can have a class field which is only a pointer, but the relationship is still composition. The difference acually lays in responsibility for the attached object's lifecycle, not in using `B` or `B*`.

Comment: @MartinBerger "Huge amount of theory is best explained through examples" is valid, supposed that the examples are neither wrong nor misleading :)

Comment: @MartinBerger Why his example is wrong: There is **absolutely no difference** between a *parameter* of a method and a *local variable* of a method. They are technically exactly the same. A *parameter* is only a *local variable* whose value is pre-filled by the caller of the method. - Take the word "value" very widely, even a parameter called "by reference" is in fact just a value (pointer) passed from outside and handled inside the method as a local variable. So called "parameters passed by reference" is only a syntactic sugar (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)!

Comment: @MartinBerger Based on your complaint about not being clear, I updated my answer, hopefully it is better now. Thanks for your feedback. Please read it, I tried to explain why it is not easy to provide simplistic examples like in this (incorrect) answer.

Comment: @MartinBerger I have added a code example to my answer to satisfy your curiosity :)

Answer (score 1):

> Can it be that the authors are referring to *aggregation* as *acquaintance* and to *composition* as *aggregation*, or am I missing something?

OMT was published in 1991, UML in 1997, and the book *Design Patterns* in 1994. So the authors use OMT *aggregation* to refer to UML *composite aggregation* (AKA *composition*).

Here are the UML definitions:

- *Aggregation* (AKA the *having* relationship) is a part–whole relationship, meaning that the whole cannot exist without the part (**not the other way round**). The part is an *essential attribute* of the whole. E.g. a car (the whole) and its engine (the part) are in aggregation since a car needs its engine to exist.
- *Association* (AKA the *acquaintance* relationship or *using* relationship) on the other hand is *not* a part–whole relationship. One object is an *accidental attribute* of the other. E.g. a car and its owner are in association since a car does not need its owner to exist.

*Note.* — Aggregation can be subdivided into two categories: *shared aggregation* where the part can exist without the whole, and *composite aggregation* (AKA *composition*, or *unique aggregation* as I like to call it) where the part cannot exist without the whole.

---

**References**

*Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software* by Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson, and John Vlissides.

> Consider the distinction between object **aggregation** and **acquaintance** and how differently they manifest themselves at compile- and run-times. Aggregation implies that one object owns or is responsible for another object. Generally we speak of an object *having* or being *part of* another object. Aggregation implies that an aggregate object and its owner have identical lifetimes.
>
> Acquaintance implies that an object merely *knows of* another object. Sometimes acquaintance is called ”association” or the “using” relationship. Acquainted objects may request operations of each other, but they aren’t responsible for each other. Acquaintance is a weaker relationship than aggregation and suggests much looser coupling between objects.

*Copying and Comparing: Problems and Solutions* by Peter Grogono and Markku Sakkinen.

> We distinguish essential and accidental attributes of an object.{Footnote: This distinction is based loosely on Aristotle’s categories.} An *essential attribute* is indisputably a part of the object; an accidental attribute is another object that is related in some way to the object in question but is not a part of it. For example, if the object in question is an instance of class `Car`, we would consider the attribute `engine` to be essential but the basic value `distanceTravelled` and the reference `owner` to be accidental. The distinction between “accidental” and “essential” is orthogonal to that between “reference” and “containment”. The model permits all four possibilities. When an attribute is represented by a reference, it is the referent object itself, not the reference, that is the accidental or essential attribute.
>
> Accidental attributes are intended as a generalization of associations. An association is a “structural relationship between peers” where “peers” are classes at the same conceptual level. An association is a kind of accidental attribute but it is not the only kind. Associations are usually implemented as references to other full-fledged objects, although more elaborate implementations have been proposed. But objects may also contain counters, flags, descriptors, and other attributes that are needed by the application software but are conceptually not part of the object.
>
> The distinction between essential and accidental is not always obvious. As a rule of thumb, the relationship between two objects is an association (and therefore accidental) if destroying one object does not logically entail destroying the other, otherwise one object is an attribute of the other. Similarly, an attribute is accidental if removing it from the object does not destroy the basic integrity of the object.

Comment: You have a good point here, reminding that GoF is based on OMT. However, the key to a right answer is the mapping with UML. When GoF writes about aggregation talking about “ownership” and “identical lifetimes” it clearly refers to a concept that in UML is called  composition. GoF reserves the term “composition” for object composition, which is a different concept (the closest in UML being an association with an owned end, aka the dot notation).

Answer (score 0):

I can only provide an answer of **aggregation** for now.

**Aggregation** has the relationship of **"part-of"**. For example a wheel is a part of a car. The car cannot exist without its wheels.

Comment: "Part-of" relationship is what nowadays is much more often called "**composition**". Your definitiion *was* used by GoF and is rather abandoned now.
BTW your example with cars is a very good illustration that providing a simple example is not simple - it always depends on the point of view of the information system you are modelling. An IS for a car repair shop cannot handle wheel as a part of the car, you would have problems with spare wheels, winter/summer set of wheels etc. (I keep 8 wheels for my car, 4 with winter and 4 with summer tyres, and they are **not** part of my car.)